# Codename one Splash screen new gui builder

Tags: java, codenameone

In the old GUI builder, I would just press "next form" in the command. In the new GUI builder, I am trying to make it through code. However, it does not wait for 5 seconds, the app goes straight into the next form.

What I want to do: stay in Splash for 5 seconds, then go to the login form. How would that work?

My forms:
`Splash.java,` that has the GIF animation.
`Login.java` (next form)
`Myapplication.java` (main form)

Main file, myapplication code:

```
public void start() {
    if(current != null){
        current.show();
        return;
    }
    new Splash().show();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
    new Login().show();
}
```

UPDATE: I added the sleep code to the LOGIN form, and every time i go there, it waits 5 seconds. Is this the optimal way to do this?
       public Login() {

```
this(com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.getGlobalResources());

   try {
Thread.sleep(3000);
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
}
```

UPDATE 2:

```
 public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();

            return;
        }
        new Splash().show();
     //   new login().show();





            new UITimer(() -> {
        new login().show();
}).schedule(3000, false, new login());
```

not working.

Comment: As @SolStack mentioned you should use `UITimer` sleep holds the EDT in place and doesn't let it draw or do anything (e.g. showing a Form) see https://www.codenameone.com/manual/edt.html

Comment: thanks. did one more update, still missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the Codename One UITimer class instead.

https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/util/UITimer.html

Something along the lines of:

```
new UITimer(() -> {
  new Login().show();
}).schedule(5000, false, this);
```

Comment: Do i put this in the main class or in the login form? Because it says "incompatible types. My application cannot be converted to form". This is red lined.

Comment: public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            
            return;
        }
        new Splash().show();
        new webtest().show();
           
            
            new UITimer(() -> {
        new Login().show();
}).schedule(3000, false, new Login());

not working.

Comment: This would go in the splash page. The UITimer waits for the scheduled amount of time before running the code in the brackets.

Comment: Just to be clear you need to show only one form. Remove ` new webtest().show(); ` and only show the splash. Then show the webtest after the timer elapses (where you show the login). Notice you just did `new Login()` and neglected the `show()`